# Rails query with two parameters does not work in production: Operator does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

This query with two parameters in Rails 4 works fine on my development system running in development mode in SQLite and in production mode in postgresql. When I move it to the production server running postgresql I receive an error that the operator does not exist. Why am I receiving this error when the version of postgresql is the same on both machines?

```
@events = Event.where("published == ? AND event_date >= ?", true,  DateTime.now.beginning_of_day).order('event_date ASC').limit(6)
```

Error:

```
E, [2014-06-14T13:26:24.470303 #28678] ERROR -- : PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean == unknown
LINE 1: ...ELECT  "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE (published == 't' AND...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE (published == 't' AND event_date >= '2014-06-14 04:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY event_date ASC LIMIT 6
I, [2014-06-14T13:26:24.470786 #28678]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 163ms
F, [2014-06-14T13:26:24.475470 #28678] FATAL -- :
```

Comment: It should be just `@events = Event.where("published = ? AND event_date >= ?", true,  DateTime.now.beginning_of_day).order('event_date ASC').limit(6)` for the `postgresql`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: boolean ==
>   unknown

There should be just one **`equal(=) sign`** should be used as stated in the PostgreSQL documentation.

Here is the **[Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-comparison.html)**

This should work

```
@events = Event.where("published = ? AND event_date >= ?", true,  DateTime.now.beginning_of_day).order('event_date ASC').limit(6)
```

And also its a bad idea to have **`two different databases`**(in your case **`SQLite`** and **`PostgresSQL`**) in **`development`** and **`production`**.

Comment: @muistooshort I've updated my answer.How it looks now?

Answer (score 2):

The comparison operator for equality in PostgreSQL or more generally SQL is not `==` with two equal signs, it's `=` with only one equal sign.

It happens that SQLite accepts both, but that's not standard.

Doc quote from http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html :

> Note that there are two variations of the equals and not equals
>   operators.
>   Equals can be either = or ==